# Different sorting in Odoo pivot view

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I'm using odoo 13. Got 2 servers, dev and staging.
Now in dev server the pivot is using Name as it's default order but in staging it uses ID as it default order. How can I make staging server use Name as it's default order?

It's odoo base module, I did not make customization in the pivot view.

![enter image description here

Staging server, uses ID as its default order

[image]

Dev server, uses Name as its default order

[image]